# Where is file that contains the Navigation Graph Design data

Tags: android, android-studio

So in my `nav_graph.xml` file, I have a lot of fragments. It took quite a while for me to drag them around in the `Design` view, and I want to make sure that is backed up. I'd like to track that in my git repository, but I have no idea where that information is stored.

I'm assuming it is in a file somewhere. Does anyone know where that file lives and what the name of it is?

**EDIT**
To be clear: I am not looking for the xml file itself. I know where that is. It's over 800 lines long, so if I didn't know where that was, it would be magic that I even had a nav graph at all.

I'm looking for the file (or wherever the information is stored) that controls how it is laid out visually in the designer. That the view where you can drag the fragment tiles around to present the graph visually.

For example, this from the Android docs:

[image]

What if the green tile was dragged above the pink/orange tile? Something has to save those coordinates, right? Or it wouldn't load again the next time I started Android Studio. *Where is that information saved??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nav_graph` itself saves all the information, related to the fragment directions and actions, which actually defines all the required information for working of the `Navigation graph`.

> I'm looking for the file (or wherever the information is stored) that controls how it is laid out visually in the designer.

Information regarding the visual representation of the nav graph is editor specific, and **Android Studio** stores it in **.idea > navEditor.xml**.

To access **.idea** directory, you've to be in project mode.

[image: Android studio]

Comment: There it is. That means that if I ever lose my `.idea` folder, the visual representation goes along with it. Damn.

Comment: No, you are not gonna lose the visual representation of your `nav_graph`, on losing the `.idea` folder. Android studio generates that visual representation using `nav_graph`, if your editor doesn't have `navEditor.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

The information is stored in `nav_graph.xml` itself. For designing layouts, menus and working with `Nav` graphs, Android Studio provides the functionality of either writing it as a code or design it, while the code will be written internally by the IDE.

[image]

In the above picture, you have been using `Design` tab to place the fragments, while on the other hand, you can check the `Code` tab, where it is written in plain `XML`

Answer (score 0):

> app > res > navigation > your_nav.xml

[image]

Comment: That's the xml file that contains the graph. I'm looking for the data that controls how it is laid out in the visual designer.

Comment: Then Just Switch to the Code Tab (Top Right Corner on your IDE) and there you will get the data of your xml graph.

Comment: Thank you, but you are not answering the question that I am asking.

Comment: Can You Make Your Question More Specific Please?